# How do I display a message after a user registers or when he hasn't logged in yet?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner. I want to know how to display an alert message after user registers. After displaying the message, it should redirect to index page.

And, when the user(who hasn't logged in), clicks a link, it should display an alert message:- You must login first.

Comment: You probably need to add some more code and clearify your problem some more so we can be more of a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts can simply be done by:

```
alert('You are registered');
```

Redirect by:

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Onclick by:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('You must login first'); return false;">Click me</a>
```

But since you are a beginner you probably have a lot more issues to handle.

Comment: This is not as simple as you answered... Registration probably send some data to server, returns something and alerts should be displayed. Maybe he wants to use Ajax or maybe not...

Comment: @Robert: of cource not but I think the question is more a guess than a real question and the poster has no clue where to begin. He (or she) needs to be more specific, add some code maybe to make clear what his (or her) problem is. Nothing is there. What I answered is al there is to answer based on the question.

Comment: I'm a "she." I have no idea how to use ajax in this

Comment: @deepz: sorry, I corrected it ;) To get ontopic: I don't think you need to look at AJAX or stuff like that just yet...just make sure you get the postback en than show a proper message as described.

Comment: Actually, my registration page is designed in html and the coding part is developed in php. And since php is server side, while javascript is client side.. I can't link them both. Atleast I want a message to pop up to show that the user has been registered.

Comment: about the user who hasn't logged in, I want it to check if user has logged in or not. If not then pop up-You must log in

Comment: Just echo something when the post is done that contains something like echo "<script>alert('hi');</script>"; Remember that yoú only are building up the HTML page on the server (with PHP) which you send back to the client to be displayed. This needs to contain the script in order to show the alert box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3410/discussion-between-baszz-and-deepz)